# PEAR/POP3 connects to mailserver, php-imap doesn't

Tags: php, apache, imap, pop3

We have a php script to handle bounce mails. Now I have to take care of switching from the PEAR NET/POP3 library to the native-ish php-imap library.

The mailserver listens on a remote server on port 110 without ssl (obviously POP3).

However I am unable to open a connection to that server using the php-imap library using the following code:

```
imap_open("{example.com:110/pop3/notls}INBOX", $username, $password);
```

This results in the following errors:

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {example.com:110/pop3/notls}INBOX in C:\xampp\htdocs\bounce-processing\info.php on line 1
Notice: Unknown: POP3 connection broken in response (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

The following PEAR POP3 implementation still works:

```
require("Net/POP3.php");
$pop3 = new Net_POP3();
$pop3->connect('example.com', 110)
$pop3->login($username, $password);
```

What I already tried:

```
imap_open("{IP-ADDRESS:110/pop3/notls}INBOX", $username, $password);
imap_open("{IP-ADDRESS:110/pop3/notls/user=$username}INBOX", $username, $password);
```

NOTE: I also tested this on different setups (CentOS / Apache 2.2, Ubuntu 14.04 / nginx, PHP 5.4, PHP 5.5, PHP 5.6, no different outcome.

What can I do? Debugging did not really help me - and that the pear class works freaks me out.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: php binary is compiled with imap / ssl and the php-imap extension is enabled in the php.ini. If you know another future-proof way to make php talk to a pop3 mailserver, let me know. We don't want to use frameworks such as phpmailer etc.

**EDIT2**: telnet login works with a success rate of 40%. I was able to successfully log in 4 out of 10 times with correct credentials.

Output of the CAPA command:

```
CAPA
+OK Here's what I can do:
STLS
TOP
USER
LOGIN-DELAY 10
PIPELINING
UIDL
IMPLEMENTATION Courier Mail Server
.
```

I don't know if thats important, but the mailserver is in fact hosted by a dedicated server housing and hosting company.

**EDIT3:** Trying to connect via

```
{IP_ADDRESS:110/pop3}
```

returns the following errors:

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {IP_ADDRESS:110/pop3} in C:\xampp\htdocs\bounce-processing\index.php on line 12
Notice: Unknown: Certificate failure for IP_ADDRESS: Server name does not match certificate.
```

**Appending the flag novalidate-cert leads to a timeout.**

Comment: It looks like you connected successfully, but then the server disconnected you.  Is there protocol debugging?  Does your server require starttls?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't even know if my server requires starttls. All I know is the hostname, the credentials and the fact that it's a pop3 server. I tried applying the /debug flag, but that didn't do anything.

Comment: telnet to your server on port 110, and try to login.  `USER x` / `PASS y`, also try the `CAPA` command.

Comment: @Max Alright. Login via telnet did work on the 3rd attempt. CAPA tells me: CAPA
+OK Here's what I can do:
STLS
TOP
USER
LOGIN-DELAY 10
PIPELINING
UIDL
IMPLEMENTATION Courier Mail Server
. also login does not always work. Seems kinda random.

Comment: @Max I updated the question, maybe you could have a look again.

Comment: Sure can you enable starttls in your library? Note this is different than tls.